# getting an error while using window.location.assign()

Tags: ajax, jquery

i want to assign new location but somehow i cant. i got an error while doing this.
Here is my code

```
jQuery.ajax({        

        type: "POST",    
        data: 'name='+ countryname,
        url: "master/ValidationCountry.jsp",
       // cache: false, 
        async: false,
        success: function(response){   
            window.location.assign(request.getContextPath() +"/jsp/admin/AdminMaster.jsp?a=1");
        // window.location.reload(); 
      // window.location.replace(request.getContextPath() +"/jsp/admin/AdminMaster.jsp?a=1");
         check = true;

        },
         error: function() {     

            check=false;
    }        
    });
```

The error i got is:
    ReferenceError: request is not defined

plz help me.

Comment: try using ${request.contextPath} instead request.getContextPath() as request is not client side variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access a http servlet requst object using javascript.

`request.getContextPath()` is a server side object, it is not available in client side.

One possible solution here is to use a global variable like `_context = <context-path-from-request>` and use it in your script

This need to be done in your view file like jsp/velocity/freemarker/tiles

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({        

        type: "POST",    
        data: 'name='+ countryname,
        url: "master/ValidationCountry.jsp",
       // cache: false, 
        async: false,
        success: function(response){   
            window.location.assign(response.d +"/jsp/admin/AdminMaster.jsp?a=1");
        // window.location.reload(); 
      // window.location.replace(response.d +"/jsp/admin/AdminMaster.jsp?a=1");
         check = true;

        },
         error: function() {     

            check=false;
    }        
    });
```

....................

and from server side web service function ,

```
[webMethod]
public static string fun()
{
return httpcontext.current.request.getContextPath();
}
```